# Angular js , $scope changes is not reflecting in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The View Part

```
 <div class="col-sm-8" data-ng-init="init_enable_disable()">
     <select class="form-control" style="margin-top: 5px;" data-ng-model="schedule.scheduleType" data-ng-change="enable_disableDiv(schedule.scheduleType);">
         <option ng-selected="{{type == defaultSelectedType}}" data-ng-repeat="type in schduleType">{{type}}
         </option>
     </select>
</div>
```

ng-repeat model

```
 $scope.schduleType = ['Recurring', 'One time'];
```

I am updating the ng-model at the later time but it does not reflect in view

```
 if (editRecord.freq_type === 1) 
 {
     alert("one time");
     $scope.schedule.scheduleType = 'One time';
 }
```

what is going wrong please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `ng-model` and assigned value from controller no need to no need to use `ng-selected` in DOM. and better to initialize from controller.

Can try it

in your controller:

```
  $scope.schduleType = ['Recurring', 'One time'];
  $scope.schedule = {};
  $scope.schedule.scheduleType = $scope.schduleType[0]; // initial select

  $scope.enable_disableDiv = function(){
    console.log($scope.schedule.scheduleType);
  }
```

in HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="schedule.scheduleType" data-ng-change="enable_disableDiv(schedule.scheduleType)">
    <option ng-repeat="type in schduleType" value="{{type}}">{{type}}</option>
</select>
```

N.B: If you want to change option value from your controller then you should use `$scope.schduleType` instead of `someValue` for referencing because of when assign value from controller then not refer the `schduleType` . like want change based on condition then use like:

```
if(editRecord.freq_type === 1) {
   $scope.schedule.scheduleType = $scope.schduleType[1];// not "one Time"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```js
`$scope.$applyAsync(function(){
   $scope.schedule.scheduleType = 'One time';
})`
```